# Unable to change/fetch the JSON value using REGEX and it returned Undefined

Tags: javascript, json, regex

I'm trying to fetch the value of currency from the JSON file and if it's USD then I need to change it to AUD.

When I tried to search the currency attribute in the json file return undefined as below:

**Code:**

```
var datastring = JSON.stringify(data);
var match = /"currency":(^")*/.exec(datastring);
console.log(match ? "Got " + match[1] : "No match");
```

**Output:**
Got undefined

**data.json:**

```
{
   "bank":[
      {
         "bankAccountType":"Saving",
         "country":"US",
         "currency":"USD",
         "firstName":"TestFirstName",
         "lastName":"TestLastName",
         "confirmed":"true"
      }
   ]
}
```

Can someone help me how to update the currency value in the JSON file and why it's returning 'undefined'

Thanks in advance.

**Updated:**

The data.json is dynamic json file and the structure will differ in every few minutes of interval. I'm only interested to get currency attribute which is always available from the data.json file and update the json before invoke it to server.

Comment: why to stringify when you can get data directly using `data.bank.currency`

Comment: Is the code shown representative of the real application? It looks rather odd to take structured data, turn it into a string, and then attempt a pattern match on it, when you could manipulate the data directly much more easily. Even if you are _given_ a JSON string, parsing it to an object and manipulating that result is likely to be a much cleaner approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const data = {
  bank: [
    {
      bankAccountType: 'Saving',
      country: 'US',
      currency: 'USD',
      firstName: 'TestFirstName',
      lastName: 'TestLastName',
      confirmed: 'true'
    }
  ]
}
const datastring = JSON.stringify(data)
const replace = datastring.replace(/"currency":"([^"]*)"/, '"currency":"AUD"')
const reparsed = JSON.parse(replace)
console.log(reparsed)
```

Answer (score 1):

The regex is wrong. Try `/"currency":"([^"]*)"/`.

Answer (score 1):

In general, doing a string match like this on structured data like JSON is likely to cause more problems than it solves: if the data is always similarly structured, you can manipulate it much more cleanly based on that structure; if it's not always similarly structured, you have no guarantee that the string manipulation is going to always do what you want.

Nonetheless, your regex is a simple one, but contains several mistakes:

```
/"currency":(^")*/
```

- `"currency":` will match literally; so far, so good (as long as there's no extra whitespace in the JSON file)
- `(`: start a capturing group
- `^`: matches the start of the string; this can't possibly succeed here
- `"`: matches a literal `"`
- `)*`: end the capturing group, and say that it can occur zero or more times

Instead of `(^")` you probably meant `[^"]` which means "any single character except for `"`". But that still won't work, because the character after the `:` **is** a `"`, so you need to match that first.

Instead of `*`, you probably want `+`, which means "one or more"; or just `{3}`, for "exactly three".

Finally, you want to capture the whole 3-character currency, not just the first part of it, so the brackets need to go around the whole thing.

Putting it together:

```
/"currency":"([^"]+)"/
```

Or:

```
/"currency":"([^"]{3})"/
```

Or, you could go much simpler, and use three "any single character" wildcards:

```
/"currency":"(...)"/
```

Comment: Very useful info. Definitely I will take a look at on this..!!

Answer (score 1):

You can change from `USD` to `AUD` using the following regex;

```
/(?<="currency":")[^"]+/
```

```js
const data = {
  bank: [{
    bankAccountType: "Saving",
    country: "US",
    currency: "USD",
    firstName: "TestFirstName",
    lastName: "TestLastName",
    confirmed: "true",
  }, ],
};

var datastring = JSON.stringify(data);
const replacedString = datastring.replace(/(?<="currency":")[^"]+/, "AUD");
console.log(replacedString);
```

Comment: Is it possible to change any currency type will be AUD. Right now the example having USD but it could be GBP, or CAD or JPY. How can I make it AUD irrespective of current currency type in the JSON file. any input on this please?

Comment: Are you sure you need the `(?=USD)` part? Wouldn't just `USD` on its own do the same thing?

Comment: @ArrchanaMohan I've changed regex to `(?<="currency":")[^"]+` then no matter the currency is, it will always replace to `AUD`

Comment: Thank you so much for yours help..! really appreciated...!

Answer (score 1):

Here an example of how to do that.

```js
let data = {
   "bank":[
      {
         "bankAccountType":"Saving",
         "country":"US",
         "currency":"USD",
         "firstName":"TestFirstName",
         "lastName":"TestLastName",
         "confirmed":"true"
      }
   ]
};

var datastring = JSON.stringify(data);

console.log(datastring);

var match = /"currency":\"[A-Z]{3}\"/.exec(datastring)[0];

let currencyVal = match.split(":")[1].replaceAll('"', '');

console.log(currencyVal);

//Too can do directly from data

console.log(data.bank[0].currency);

//If the data is a string you can use JSON.parse() function for get a JSON object.

//https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

//Supposing you get the JSON with type string:

let jsonObj = JSON.parse(datastring);

console.log(jsonObj.bank[0].currency);

//If you want replace USD to AUD you can do for example:

jsonObj.bank[0].currency = jsonObj.bank[0].currency.replace("USD", "AUD");

console.log(jsonObj.bank[0].currency);
```